# How to downgrade google_fonts version In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, google-font-api

So I was just building an app & I realized I kept getting an error. The error was coming from a google_fonts package that I installed. Apparently, **google_fonts^6.2.0** just dropped last night & it has a bunch of bugs. I want to use google_fonts version 6.1.0 but I don't know how. Every time I enter **Flutter pub add google_fonts** in the terminal, it keeps downloading the latest version which is 6.2.0 & I don't want that. I tried entering the version number in the pubspec.yaml, then entering **Flutter pub get** in the terminal but that didn't work either. I just want to use google_fonts^6.1.0, if there is a manual way of installing it, I'd like to know as well. Please help.

Comment: `^6.1.0` means `>= 6.1.0 <7.0.0`, which is why the version installed is still `6.2.0`. See: [Semantic versions](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning#semantic-versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit `pubspec.yaml`, save after editing:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: 6.1.0
```

2. Run `flutter pub get`.
3. Clean and Rebuild (Optional but Recommended):

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad I was able to help.